# Get instance failure when trying connect to ms sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

Trying connect to ms sql from c# code, but get this error. If I make simple connection like this:

```
  String connect = "server=MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; database=mydb; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
          con.ConnectionString = connect;
```

But when I try connecto from app.config, I get this error:

```
      String connect = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
         con.ConnectionString = connect ;
```

Here is xml code:

```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
       <add key="connectionString" value="server=MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; database=mydb;       Integrated        Security=SSPI;"/>
      </appSettings>
     </configuration>
```

Some ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us the error message that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your connection string in app.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connect" connectionString="Data
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then get you connection string as

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString
```

Example Conn string:

```
<add name="NorthWind" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="server=.;database=NorthWind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Comment: I don't understand what I need insert instead of 

          AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf

Comment: In your case you don't need it. A simple example would be (see edit).

Comment: unfortunately again this error

here is my code:

 String con_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWind"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Great that it worked for you. Consider accepting it as answer if at all the answer helped you.

Comment: emm, sorry but I can't find, where I must do it?

Comment: Peoooople, explain me please, where can I vote here for Your answers?

Comment: when someone answers your question then there is a disabled tick mark just below rating column, if you check that tick mark, that will consider that you have accepted that answer. Use the Up/Down arroe to vote up/down.

Answer (score 0):

try this

String connect = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=mydb;Integrated Security=True;"
              con.ConnectionString = connect;